# Multinomial logit: mlogit vs statsmodels

Tags: r, python, mlogit, statsmodels

I am doing a comparison between mlogit in R and statsmodels in python and have had trouble getting them to produce the same result. I'm wondering if the difference is a result of libraries or I am specifying something incorrectly. Any help would be appreciated.

I am using the "TravelMode" dataset to test the two.
In R:

```
> library("mlogit")
> library("AER")
> data("TravelMode", package="AER")
> write.csv(TravelMode, "travelmode.csv")
> TM <- mlogit.data(TravelMode, choice = "choice", shape = "long", 
                    chid.var = "individual", alt.var = "mode", drop.index = TRUE)
> TMlogit = mlogit(mFormula(choice ~ vcost), TM)
> summary(TMlogit)
Call:
mlogit(formula = mFormula(choice ~ vcost), data = TM, method = "nr", 
    print.level = 0)

Frequencies of alternatives:
    air   train     bus     car 
0.27619 0.30000 0.14286 0.28095 

nr method
4 iterations, 0h:0m:0s 
g'(-H)^-1g = 0.000482 #'
successive function values within tolerance limits 

Coefficients :
                    Estimate Std. Error t-value  Pr(>|t|)    
train:(intercept) -0.3885180  0.2622157 -1.4817 0.1384272    
bus:(intercept)   -1.3712065  0.3599380 -3.8096 0.0001392 ***
car:(intercept)   -0.8711172  0.3979705 -2.1889 0.0286042 *  
vcost             -0.0138883  0.0055318 -2.5106 0.0120514 *  
---
Signif. codes:  0 ‘***’ 0.001 ‘**’ 0.01 ‘*’ 0.05 ‘.’ 0.1 ‘ ’ 1

Log-Likelihood: -280.54
McFadden R^2:  0.011351 
Likelihood ratio test : chisq = 6.4418 (p.value = 0.011147)
```

In statsmodels:

```
> import pandas as pd
> import statsmodels.formula.api as smf
> TM = pd.read_csv('travelmode.csv')
> TM = pd.concat([TM, pd.get_dummies(TM['mode'])], axis=1)
> TMlogit = smf.mnlogit('choice ~ train + bus + car + vcost -1', TM)
> TMlogit_fit = TMlogit.fit()
Optimization terminated successfully.
         Current function value: 0.550273
         Iterations 6
> TMlogit_fit.summary()
<class 'statsmodels.iolib.summary.Summary'>
"""
                          MNLogit Regression Results                          
==============================================================================
Dep. Variable:                      y   No. Observations:                  840
Model:                        MNLogit   Df Residuals:                      836
Method:                           MLE   Df Model:                            3
Date:                Thu, 17 Mar 2016   Pseudo R-squ.:                 0.02145
Time:                        15:04:48   Log-Likelihood:                -462.23
converged:                       True   LL-Null:                       -472.36
                                        LLR p-value:                 0.0001497
=================================================================================
y=choice[yes]       coef    std err          z      P>|z|      [95.0% Conf. Int.]
---------------------------------------------------------------------------------
train            -0.3249      0.172     -1.891      0.059        -0.662     0.012
bus              -1.4468      0.205     -7.070      0.000        -1.848    -1.046
car              -0.7247      0.157     -4.603      0.000        -1.033    -0.416
vcost            -0.0105      0.002     -6.282      0.000        -0.014    -0.007
=================================================================================
"""
```

I would think the values of the coefficients would be closer to each other when comparing between the two models. Any help would be appreciated.

Comment: Those two are **not** the same model. For a recent discussion about the status of discrete choice models for statsmodels see the thread of https://groups.google.com/d/msg/pystatsmodels/IoQckMN32zA/_qBslon1BgAJ  and the newly published package `pylogit` that reproduces R's mnlogit results.

Comment: @user333700, why not post an answer explaining how & why the 2 models are not the same?

Comment: FWIW, this strikes me as potentially on topic. (It may well be off topic, but I can't tell.)

Comment: @gung I was hoping somebody else provides an explanation because I'm short in time right now. A brief answer is here http://stackoverflow.com/questions/34548375/multinomial-conditional-logit-regression-why-statsmodel-fails-on-mlogit-package/34566565#34566565 In Stata the R's mnlogit equivalent is asclogit and the statsmodels equivalent in Stata is mlogit, as far as I know.

Comment: @user333700 I was able to achieve identical results using pylogit, thanks.

Answer (score 7):

I'm the creator of `pylogit`. Thanks for using my package!

To answer your question, the differences in estimation results comes from differences in the way choice data is represented in `statsmodels` versus `mlogit`. The `TravelMode` dataset is in long format natively (i.e. when you wrote it to csv). I.e. it has one row per alternative per observation. However, `statsmodels` assumes ones data is in wide format, with one row per observation. Thus there are 4 times as many "observations" in the `statsmodels` model (840) than there are in your `mlogit` model. Try calling `length(unique(TravelMode$individual))`.

Moreover, your variables (`pd.get_dummies(TM['mode'])`) in your `statsmodel` model do not represent alternative specific constants, but are simply the alternative identifiers for each row of the long-format data. This is in contrast to the intercepts that were estimated in the `mlogit` model.

Comment: timothyb0912 can you provide an example where `pylogit` results are replicated using `statsmodels`? Maybe for the simplest case of multinomial logit

Comment: @Gigi

Example 1: 
https://github.com/timothyb0912/pylogit/blob/master/examples/notebooks/mlogit%20Benchmark--Train%20and%20Fishing.ipynb

Example 2:
https://github.com/timothyb0912/pylogit/blob/master/examples/notebooks/mlogit_Benchmark--Heating.ipynb

Comment: @Gigi sorry for my earlier response. I thought you wanted a replication from mlogit in R. I don't have any replications using statsmodels because that package didn't support the use cases I needed. In fact, when I first created pylogit, I tried to have it added to statsmodels (https://groups.google.com/g/pystatsmodels/c/IoQckMN32zA/m/_qBslon1BgAJ)

I can create one using https://www.statsmodels.org/stable/examples/notebooks/generated/discrete_choice_overview.html#Multinomial-Logit, but it may take me a while to prioritize it.
I'm happy to take a pull-request in the meantime with a notebook.

Comment: Got it! thanks for your response.